# Mysql Login issues

Tags: mysql

I have very strange issues

I have developed yetiforce crm in local system and migrated to globehost sever .
the mysql version is 5.6 in local and hosting server but my login does not work 
in hosting server what could be the possible reason.

Regards

Comment: Do you expect a list of all 4913 reasons for your login not working? Just enter it in google and read every result, one of it might be it. Or you could narrow it down and add the error messages you get and describe in more detail what you did to migrate (e.g. if you moved both the application and the database to the hosting server or just the db and expect the app to work on a local client with a remote server; what values in your config you changed; ...)

Comment: if you want more details let me know,  I am not looking for harping suggestion

Comment: As I said: to narrow your problem down, you would need to add the error messages you get and describe in more detail what you did to migrate (e.g. if you moved both the application and the database to the hosting server or just the db and expect the app to work on a local client with a remote server; what values in your config you changed; ...). Please also add if you can login at all (with the mysql client) with these credentials, and from where (from server, from your local pc, both). Also add if you want to login as the "root"-user (otherwise, the specific username does not matter).

Comment: my local system has php5 and mysql 5.6, the server too has the same configuration. first I thought the problem is with the password so went and reset the password via command line inside mysql-DB, still same error occurred. what is challenging is I don't see any error in logfiles. if I restored the data base from the hosted database on some other local system it works and I am able to login into the application.

Comment: I don't think you are doing it intentionally, but you answered exactly zero of my questions (if I assume that at least your app will show some kind of error message when trying to connect) - just to give you an impression how hard it can be to answer questions with few details. The more details you add, the more likely it is that the required information is in there. So to start again: Can you connect to the server db a) from a mysql client on the server b) from a local mysql client? Also (and probably the main issue): do you run your app on your local pc or did you move it to the server too?

Answer (score -1):

I got the solutions, it had to do with the permission of the files, the directory should be 755 and files had to be 644, some of the files had different permission which was causing the problems